# Integrating a Brownian Bridge conditioned above a linear boundary

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

**The Setup:**

A *Brownian Bridge* $B$ is a Brownian Motion on time interval $[0, 1]$ conditioned such that $B(0) = B(1) = 0$.  I have a function $f(t) = mt+b$ with $m, b$ set such that $C(t) \le 0$ for $t \in [0, 1]$.  Define a new process $C$ that is a Brownian Bridge conditioned such that $C(t) \ge f(t)$ for any $t \in [0, 1]$.

**The Problem:**

I am interested in finding a density function for the random variable $\int_0^1 C(t) dt$.

**A Possibly Useful Fact:**

If $f(t) = 0$ identically, then $C$ is called a *Brownian Excursion Process*, and the density function for its integral is known.

Answer (score 1):

If this can be of any help, the probability that the bridge crosses $f(t)$ on $[0,1]$ is given by
$$
\mbox{exp}(-2b(b+m)),
$$
you can find out more and proof in this article by [Scheike](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3214581).